# how to customize button and text in odoo 10

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, css, odoo-10

I installed odoo from version 10 and 
I would like to change the background color of the text button "" **Reprendre** "" ie change the background color and buttons of purple color in red and I can not locate the file css concerned to be able to make the changes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you hope to change the style directly, go to the addons and find below file.

```
\addons\web\static\src\less\variables.less
```

You can change the color code of the 5th line, save and refresh page.

```
@odoo-font-size-base: 13px;

// Colors
@odoo-brand-primary: #7c7bad;
@odoo-brand-optional: red;
@odoo-brand-secondary: #f0eeee;
@odoo-brand-lightsecondary: #e2e2e0;
```

Comment: Thank you and one last question how to change the background color of the footer <<Powered by Odoo >>

Comment: You could add some CSS to the end of that file
`.body > div.o_main > div.o_sub_menu > div.o_sub_menu_footer {
    background-color: #123456;
}`

Comment: Modifying the style directly is easy to do, but if you need to distribute something, may consider putting it inside a module or creating a theme; there should be some tutorials online.